# Highlighting periods using a dummy variable in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, highlight, dummy-variable

I have two time series yield and fx and a dummy. How can I plot the two series in ggplot and highlight (shade) the areas where the dummy is 1? The header of the data set below.

```
date    dummy   yield   fx
1/1/1990    0   10.029  1.261184049
1/2/1990    0   10.036  1.261008068
1/3/1990    0   10.119  1.258932591
1/4/1990    0   10.02   1.261410528
1/5/1990    0   10.013  1.261586847
1/6/1990    1   10.066  1.260255526
1/7/1990    1   10.057  1.260481006
1/8/1990    1   10.057  1.260481006
1/9/1990    1   10.067  1.260230488
1/10/1990   1   10.186  1.257272051
```

I tried it with rect similar to the code below but this did not work.

```
ggplot(dummies, aes(date)) + 
geom_line(aes(y = yield, colour = "yield")) + 
geom_line(aes(y = fx, colour = "fx")) +
geom_rect(aes(xmin=-Inf, xmax=Inf, ymin=0, ymax=1),
          colour=alpha("grey20", 0.5), fill.alpha=0.5)
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you only have this one period that needs to be shaded, I would just use `annotate`. Otherwise, you could make use of `geom_rect` with some means of pulling just unique dates.

I converted your date column to Date objects to get better formatting and to be able to use functions like `min` and `max`. Then the dummy data is in a separate dataframe that's filtered for observations where `dummy == 1` and where the date is either the first or last of the `dummy == 1` dates. This makes the `xmin` and `xmax` of the annotation. I set the `ymin` for the annotation to 0, but you could set it to anything that makes sense for your data.

I also saw your comments above about needing the gridlines to be visible, so I used `theme_light` instead. You could change the color of your gridlines if it's an issue.

```r
library(tidyverse)

# main data frame
df <- "date    dummy   yield   fx
1/1/1990    0   10.029  1.261184049
1/2/1990    0   10.036  1.261008068
1/3/1990    0   10.119  1.258932591
1/4/1990    0   10.02   1.261410528
1/5/1990    0   10.013  1.261586847
1/6/1990    1   10.066  1.260255526
1/7/1990    1   10.057  1.260481006
1/8/1990    1   10.057  1.260481006
1/9/1990    1   10.067  1.260230488
1/10/1990   1   10.186  1.257272051" %>% 
    read_table2() %>%
    mutate(date2 = lubridate::mdy(date)) %>%
    gather(key = measure, value = value, yield, fx)

head(df)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 5
#>   date     dummy date2      measure value
#>   <chr>    <int> <date>     <chr>   <dbl>
#> 1 1/1/1990     0 1990-01-01 yield    10.0
#> 2 1/2/1990     0 1990-01-02 yield    10.0
#> 3 1/3/1990     0 1990-01-03 yield    10.1
#> 4 1/4/1990     0 1990-01-04 yield    10.0
#> 5 1/5/1990     0 1990-01-05 yield    10.0
#> 6 1/6/1990     1 1990-01-06 yield    10.1

# dummy data frame: dummy == 1, only min & max dates
dummy <- df %>% 
    filter(dummy == 1) %>% 
    filter(date2 %in% c(min(date2), max(date2))) %>%
    select(dummy, date2) %>%
    unique()

ggplot(df, aes(x = date2, y = value, color = measure)) +
    annotate(geom = "rect", xmin = min(dummy$date2), xmax = max(dummy$date2), ymin = 0, ymax = Inf, fill = "gray", alpha = 0.4) +
    geom_line() +
    theme_light()
```

[image]

Created on 2018-04-18 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 1):

Give this a go:

```
library(tidyr)

dummies2<- gather(dummies, key="type", value="value", c("yield", "fx"))

ggplot(dummies2, aes(x=date, y=value, colour=type, group=type)) + 
  geom_segment(aes(y=-Inf, yend=Inf,x=date, xend=date, alpha=dummy),inherit.aes = F,colour="black", size=5)+
               scale_alpha_continuous(range=c(0,0.3))+
  guides(alpha=F)+
  geom_line()
```

(Note that the annotations are added as marks on discrete timepoints. Doing it otherwise, as interperiod shading is also possible.

Comment: the problem now is that it fills the period where the dummy is one so that the other lines (yield and fx) are not visible anymore. Lighter colours don't make it any better. It seems to plot a second layer. Do you know how we could fix that?

Comment: Simply invert the order of geom_line and geom_segment. Each separate element is plotted in the order that it is called

Comment: this looks much better thanks. However, I think it's not shading the specific area but filling it completely so that grid lines in the chart disappear. Is there another way so that it only highlights the background?

Comment: Grid lines are still present, albeit hard to see. Change your range of alpha values like so to make the background more visible scale_alpha_continuous(range=c(0,0.15))

Comment: still no gridlines in sight. Even after dropping it down to 0.05 or choosing a different colour. Is there something else I could try? thanks in advance.

Comment: I still have gridlines here. Could you give me your dummies file with dput() and I'll try to reproduce the issue?