# ggplot2 place rect or tile based on factor in time series R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a line plot that I want to overlay a rectangle or colored band in the background based on when a certain column is 1 or not.

Here is an example:

```
df <- data.frame(date = seq.Date(as.Date("2015-01-01"), as.Date("2016-12-01"), by = "month"),
           value = c(rep(NA, 5), rep(1, 2), rep(NA, 3), rep(1, 10), rep(NA, 4)))

df2 <- data.frame(date = seq.Date(as.Date("2015-01-01"), as.Date("2016-12-01"), by = "month"),
                 values = c(rep(1, 10), rep(2, 10), rep(3, 4)))
```

What I have tried:

```
ggplot(df2, aes(x = date, y = values)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_tile(data = df, aes(fill = "value"), inherit.aes = FALSE)

Error in eval(substitute(list(...)), `_data`, parent.frame()) : 
  object 'x' not found
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(x, na.rm = na.rm) :
  no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x, na.rm = na.rm) :
```

I just want to have the line plot and then wherever `df$value` is `1` have the background colored in grey.

---

From Melissa's solution I am close but getting weird lines:

[image]

Comment: Not quite a dupe, but [this previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49900518/highlighting-periods-using-a-dummy-variable-in-ggplot2) might help

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to play with this a little bit, but this should get you most of what you want:

```
df3 <- left_join(df2, df)


ggplot(df3, aes(x = date, y = values)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_tile(aes(x = date, fill = !is.na(value)), width = 30, height = .4, alpha = 0.5, color = NA) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("gray20", NA))
```

or to have the background extend over the entire range of the y-axis:

```
ggplot(df3, aes(x = date, y = values)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_tile(aes(x = date, fill = !is.na(value)), width = 30, height = Inf, alpha = 0.5) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("gray20", NA))
```

The width isn't quite right at this point - you might try switching to `geom_rect` to define the widths by the left and right points instead of the middle (see the instructions of `geom_rect` or `geom_tile` to get part figured out.

Comment: Thanks, this is very close. I'm getting weird lines up and down my plot. I posted an image in my question as an edit

Comment: those re probably from the borders of the `geom_tile` rectangles - you may need to play with that.  I would definitely try `geom_rect`

Comment: I figured it out. Just set `color = NA` in the geom_tile call and it gets rid of the borders. If you add this to your solution I can accept

Answer (score 2):

Here is an answer with `geom_rect`, which is another choice for this application. `ggplot` is pretty forgiving about subsetting the data in the `geom` specification, so something like this might work for your situation:

```
df <- data.frame(date = seq.Date(as.Date("2015-01-01"), as.Date("2016-12-01"), by = "month"),
             value = c(rep(1, 6), rep(NA, 4), rep(1, 10), rep(NA, 4)))
df2 <- data.frame(date = seq.Date(as.Date("2015-01-01"), as.Date("2016-12-01"), by = "month"),
              values = c(rep(1, 10), rep(2, 10), rep(3, 4)))

library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)
ggplot() + 
  geom_rect(data=subset(df,value==1), aes(xmin=date, xmax=date+months(1), ymin=-Inf, ymax=Inf), fill="light grey", colour=NA) +
  geom_line(data=df2, aes(x = date, y = values)) +
  theme_classic()
```

This approach also maintains `df` and `df2` separately, but I agree that it would be better to join them, since you have the same dates in each.

[image]

Comment: I think this will fail if there are more than 1 'group' of 1's in df. Because it will group them all together and make a rectangle from the min date to the max date.

Comment: @jchaykow, Good point. Edited the code to adapt to this example, using `lubridate` to shade the months where `value==1`.

Comment: I'm sorry, @phalteman, can you explain me why in xmax you have date + months(1) ? I don't get the months(1) part. I'm dealing with this same issue but I have quarterly data (as.yearqrt)

Comment: @MagdalenaCortina - that line says to shade from the first day of the month (the values provided in `date`) to the first day of the next month - i.e., shade the entire month. The plot actually has separate grey blocks for each month in the shaded areas, which you can see more clearly if you use `colour="black"`.